# How to download image from URL using beautiful soup in high quality?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **download images using beautiful soup While Importing a list of URLs from .CSV file**. Now I am getting results like below,

```
<img class="pick" src="backup/remote_2109image/008f3ef7-1da9-11ec-abad-88ae1db4aa6901.jpg" width="350height=616\"/>
```

In the below code, I am **trying to get an image from URL that has the class 'pick'**

Now, How Will I download this in a folder?

```
import csv
import requests
import os
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

 with open('cat.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        imagesname = ' '.join(row)
        r = requests.get(imagesname)

        soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser') 
        tables = soup.find_all('img', class_='pick')
    
        for image in tables:
            print(image)
```

Comment: you can fetch image content with `img_content = requests.get(url + image["src"]).content` which has byte content of image. Now you write this into a file using `("my_img.jpg", "wb").write(img_content)`

Comment: this is not working, also I have to save the image name the same as shown in the code, no hard coded image name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to download image from URL which is in CSV file

```
import csv
import requests
import os
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open('cat.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        imagesname = ' '.join(row)
        r = requests.get(imagesname)

        soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
        tables = soup.find_all('img', class_='pick')

        for image in tables:
            img_url = image.get('src').replace('\\', '/')
            real_url = "domain-name" + img_url
            
            img_name = str(img_url.split('/')[-1])
 
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(real_url, os.path.join(
                path, img_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```py
with open('cat.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        imagesname = ' '.join(row)
        r = requests.get(imagesname)

        soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser') 
        tables = soup.find_all('img', class_='pick')

        inParsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(imagesname) # break down url
        rootUrl = f'{inParsed.scheme}://{inParsed.netloc}' # to get root
  
        for image in tables:
            imageUrl = urllib.parse.urljoin(rootUrl, imageUrl.get('src')) # add root to src
            saveImgAs = [u for u in imageUrl.split('/') if u][-1] # get name from link

            with open(saveImgAs, "wb") as f:
                f.write(requests.get(imageUrl).content) # download
                f.close()
            
            print(saveImgAs, image)
```

I'm not entirely sure about the formation of `imageUrl` nor of how consistent your image `src` values might be - if I had a few of your `row` values, I would have been able to run a few tests first, but hopefully this works